# Collection Filtering (Pass List<String> to View and Back to Controller)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, razor, variable-assignment

I'm working on writing an enhanced search functionality for a collection that I have and I have run into an issue.  I am trying to store a List in a hidden field in a form so that I can add to it each time that the user posts the form.

Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(Int32 page = 0, List<String> filters = null, String filter = "", Int32 pageSize = 10, Boolean sortAscending = true, String sortBy = "Title") {
    UserContext uc = SecurityHelpers.GetUserData();
    LinkedList<SongViewModel> svm = new LinkedList<SongViewModel>();

    var songs = _songRepository.FindAll()
                               .Where(a => a.Title.Contains(filter) ||
                                           a.Lyrics.Contains(filter) ||
                                           a.Description.Contains(filter));

    ViewBag.ResultsCount = songs.Count();
    ViewBag.Page = page;
    ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;
    ViewBag.SortAscending = sortAscending;

    if (filters == null) {
        filters = new List<String>();
    }
    filters.Add(filter);
    ViewBag.Filters = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(filters);

    songs = songs.Sort(sortBy, sortAscending)
                 .Skip(page * pageSize)
                 .Take(pageSize);

    foreach (Song s in songs) {
        ((LinkedList<SongViewModel>)svm).AddLast(new SongViewModel(uc.SongWriterId) {
            Song = s
        });
    }
    return View("songs", svm);
}
```

Here is my view code:

```
<li>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="filter" />
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Filters" name="filters" />
</li>
```

When I submit the form, everything seems to work, however, ViewBag.Filters now contains a list of lists?

- The first run of the Index action shows a value of [""] for Filters in the hidden field.
- If I submit a value of 'asdf' for filter I get ["[\"\"]","asdf"].
- If I submit again with a value of 'foo' for filter I get ["[\"[\\"\\"]\",\"asdf\"]","foo"].

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?  It seems that the Json parser is interpreting the value of filters as a single element in the list, I just have no idea how to fix this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

If I convert the list into a CSV string the model binder interprets it correctly.

```
ViewBag.Filters = filters.Aggregate("", (s, x) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? x : s + ", " + x);
```